# Small cross reverse proxy server that can be configures and redistrubution

Tags: reverse-proxy

Hi as the title says I'm looking for a cross platform reverse proxy that can be pre configured and then redistributed.

Reason

There are multiple people running 5 apps on servers

locahost:8080
locahost:8081
locahost:8082
locahost:8083
locahost:8084

Now with the reverse proxy I would like to set it up so

localhost/one
localhost/two
localhost/three
localhost/four
localhost/five

I could manually set it up with Apache or something similar for each person but it seems wiser to pre configure something and then just redistribute it so everyone can just run it and it works out the box. I was thinking of python as its cross platform but haven't found anything suitable yet. Does anyone know of anything that doesn't have tons of frills and is lightweight?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is rather late, but [Node.js](http://nodejs.org) has a number of proxy components that would fit. [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) being the most commonly quoted.

Node.js works well on multiple platforms (Windows, Mac, Linux at least) and is based on Google's "V8" JavaScript engine. It is non-blocking and highly performant.